# How often does the Outlook exchange server pull the web-addin manifest if they are "sideload" installed via URL

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

If the web-addin is not submitted to the Office store, but simply installed by the users via its URL. So the developer update the manifest content without changing its URL. Wonder how long does this change (or will it ever) get to the users?

Have been reading the [Outlook web addin manifest document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/manifests) on Office Dev Ceneter, but did not find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The add-in manifest is accessed via its URL on installation and after that the XML for the manifest is stored in Exchange. In order to update the manifest in Exchange, you will need to install the add-in again using the same URL.

#### Exchange On-Premise

You can install add-ins for all users in an organization in Exchange through Exchange Control Panel for On-Premise users ([Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943752(v=exchg.150).aspx)).

#### Exchange Online / Office 365

You can install add-ins for users through centralized deployment for Office 365 users ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment)). There are some considerations for deploying an add-in for Office 365:

- Users must be using Office 2016
- Users must be in the top level group, as nested groups are not supported.
- Users' mailboxes must be hosted in Exchange Multi-Tenant or Exchange Dedicated vNext

#### Outlook.com

In order to update add-in manifests for Outlook.com users, the manifest must be resubmitted to to the Office store.

Comment: Thank you! We are trying to figure out a way to rollout new addin changes without requiring the users to install it again. The only way we come up is to submit our addin to the Office store. So when we want to rollout a new version, we can resubmit it again and the users will get it automatically. Is there any other way to achieve this purpose?

Comment: I clarified some options for you depending on the type of user you are targeting. You can resubmit your addin to the Office store, but if you are deploying an add-in for users in an organization, you can use Exchange Control Panel or Centralized Deployment to release updates to users. There may be a delay when updating the manifest as they are cached locally.

Comment: One more question about Exchange Control Panel and Centralized Deployment. If the admin turns on a certain addin in their org using these applications by choosing the addin from the Office Store, does any addin update in the Office Store rollout to users automatically or it requires the admin perform certain operations?

Comment: The add-in should update automatically if installed from the office store