# Outlook Manifest update server domain not working

Tags: deployment, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook Web Addin, running in O365. This is currently hosted at my first server. `(oldserver.domain.com)`
I wanted to change the address the addin calls, so I changed all Urls in the Manifest file to `(newserver.domain.com)`and uploded it via the Microsoft 356 Admin Center. The new manifest was accepted, but the Addin is always calling the `oldserver.domain.com`. Since these updates sometime take a while to finish, I waited for the next morning.

I found this:
[How often does the Outlook exchange server pull the web-addin manifest if they are "sideload" installed via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052759/how-often-does-the-outlook-exchange-server-pull-the-web-addin-manifest-if-they-a)
With this description it should already work. How can I get my addin to call the new url?

Comment: Did you try to change/increment the add-in version in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I did. Otherwise it would not accept it.

Comment: Have you tried to clear the browser cache on the end-user machine?

Comment: I am using the OWA. Yes I cleared and disabled the cache.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest removing the old add-in and then deploying anew. If you did everything written correctly the add-in should be deployed and appeared on the user side.

Comment: I already recreated the addin with the new Manifest. It still keeps displaying the old version in the 'Get Extension' Dialog. (I added the Manifest version number to the description within my build.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes may take an effect in up to 24 hours, not just next morning. You can find the following statement in the [Deploy add-ins in the admin center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide) article:

> Outlook add-ins can take up to 24 hours to appear on app ribbons.

Comment: The 24 hours are passed. Nothing changed yet.

Comment: Did you try to restart Outlook and sync the data?

Comment: I recreated the app and then waited for 24 hours.

Comment: BTW: This behavior is reproducable. If you are going to change the app server's address. It will not redeploy the app. It will always access the old server until you recreate the app. All the other changes (except Description and Title) won't be applied either.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is necessary to enable and disable the add-in (multiple times) from the Office 365 admin center.

[image: Office 365 admin center]